# Makefile binary compilation

Tags: compilation, cryptocurrency

I ran make -f makefile.unix and I installed the required dependencies and all worked great but when I ran the procuded binary file on another computer without dependencies it didnt work.
And it gave this error: **./iocoind: error while loading shared libraries: libboost_program_options.so.1.65.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory**

Maybe can someone help me with this because I'm struggling importing that library in the make file too.
So here is the makefile:
https://github.com/IOCoin/DIONS/blob/master/src/makefile.unix

Btw, Im having this issue on linux.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, if your binary has dependencies, you need those on the target machine in order to run the binary.  Is there a question here?

Comment: But how can I import those depedencies in makefile so they gonna all link together and not show error when I'll run the binary. Thats the issue.

Comment: You can not "import" dependencies in Makefiles. Make does not support packaging dependencies. You would want a higher level tool such as CMake or Meson, which can generate Makefiles, install scripts and detect dependencies (in a declarative way instead of imperative as raw make does). All that make knows are flags and dependencies between recipes. It does not know which unit comes from which library.

Comment: Alright but is there any way through make file to make it work? So the produced binary file gonna work without dependencies?